# Help with functional property

Tags: functions

I am sorry, but I do not know how to search this. I apologize in advance.

Assume I have a set $X$ and a map $f:X\rightarrow X$; there are $n$ elements $x_1,... x_n\in X$ such that $f(x_k)=x_{k+1}$ and $f(x_n)=x_1$.

Does this property have a name?

Comment: That's a specific permutation (more or less): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition
Also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Definition
Don't think the functional-analysis tag is appropriate here btw

Comment: I would say something like "there is an $n-$cycle under iterations of $f$."

Comment: Can you suggest a better tag?

Comment: Maybe "permutations" or "permutation-cycles".  Not really happy with either, though, since of course your function $f$ need not be a permutation on all of $X$.

Comment: I don't think this property has a name. It is equivalent to saying that there exists a nonempty finite subset $Y \subseteq X$ such that $f(Y) = Y$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Functional analysis is a subfield of analysis, and is *not* about the discrete theory of functions on sets as is being discussed here. I will edit the tag to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this property has a name. It may help to note that it is equivalent to saying that there exists a nonempty finite subset $Y \subseteq X$ such that $f(Y) = Y$.

If you have to make use of this condition very often, you can give it your own name! For example you could write

> *Definition.* We say that a function $f : X \to X$ has property **P** if there exists a nonempty finite $Y \subseteq X$ such that $f(Y) = Y$.